How do I use selenium in python to capture a screenshot when the alert is displayed on the browser?
I have been trying to look for a way to capture a screenshot using selenium in python once the alert is displayed after clicking a button on the web page. But, unfortunately it keeps giving the "unexpected alert open" error.
Here is the following code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os

# Initialize the WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

try:
    # Open the Selenium Alerts page
    driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/web/alerts.html")

    # Trigger the alert by clicking the alert button
    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "click me").click()

    # Switch to the alert immediately to handle it
    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
    print("Alert text:", alert.text)  # Print alert text to confirm

    # Capture the screenshot with the alert open
    screenshot_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "alert_screenshot.png")
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(screenshot_path)  # Alternative method to save the screenshot
    print(f"Screenshot saved at {screenshot_path}")

    # Accept the alert after taking the screenshot
    alert.accept()

finally:
    # Close the browser
    driver.quit()

Is there anything you can do to fix the error? Your help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

you can set the unexpected alert behavior of the driver.  There is an option for "ignore" methinks. (the default behavior includes "notify" which means throw an exception) Not sure if that helps get a screenshot of the alert, though.  You could instead take a system level screenshot.
